# Is there a way to Unload a file from FilterGraph

Tags: delphi, directshow, dspack

Is FilterGraph supposed to be used once per file? If I render some file to FilterGraph and then try to load another one, it plays both of them. So should I recreate a FilterGraph for the second file or is there any way to unload a first file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are not checking what you are actually having in your graphs, otherwise there just cannot be questions like asked. There is no connection between files and filter graphs. Any filter graph might have zero to infinity files referenced by contained filters. File use/reuse/render to graph are inapplicable to filter graphs in first place.

What you are supposedly having is adding new filters to existing filter graph without removing earlier added. Checking graph topology would reveal this immediately. If your intent is to play another file, you should either enumerate and remove earlier added filters (this is the "unload" you are looking for) and then start adding new ones, or you just create a new filter graph from fresh. The latter makes more sense unless you have specific reasons to reuse certain filters.

Comment: I think this question's originates from DSPack library which does not provide any filter enumeration capabilities.

Comment: @FreeConsulting, it has perfect support for filter enumeration. It even comes with a demo showing a filter graph.

Comment: @TLama, at which demo project I should look exactly?

Comment: @FreeConsulting, oh, sorry. It's probably not a demo project, but a [`design time editor`](https://code.google.com/p/dspack/source/browse/trunk/src/DSPack/BaseFilterEditor.pas) (don't know, it's a long time I've worked with DSPack). What I'm sure about is that you can build a filter graph by yourself.

Comment: @TLama, yeah, that's a wrapped/UI around [enumeration of installed filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375615). To examine the filter on the given graph, we have to resort back to DirectShow API. The same is with pin enumeration. Personally, I did several exercises with DSPack, found what it poses more problems than solves and finally thrown it away and rewrote rest of the code in API.

Comment: With or without DSPack, one of the first things DirectShow dev should master is reviewing filter graph topology on runtime. There are builtiful tools out there for this tasks, and this resolves lots of beginner's issues.